# Erro de data ORACLE

Tags: php, oracle, data

Embora tenha muitos materiais sobre o assunto , nada ainda me ajudou a resolver.

Estou tentando fazer um consulta simples em um banco oracle e recebo um erro, segue o erro.

```
 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Segue minha consulta.

```
   try {
        $linha = '';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM SGT.VW_INFOGED";
        $p_sql = Conexao::conexaoOracle()->prepare($sql);
        $execute = $p_sql->execute();
        if ($execute) {
            $linha = $p_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            print_r($linha);
        } else {
            print_r($p_sql->errorInfo());
            return 'ERRO... CONTATE O SUPORTE';
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo "ERRRO" . $ex . "";
    }
```

Estrutura da View

```
  Nome                  Nulo     Tipo         
--------------------- -------- ------------ 
ID_NOTA               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(27) 
NUMERO_NOTA                    VARCHAR2(10) 
REMETENTE_NOME                 VARCHAR2(50) 
REMETENTE_CNPJ                 VARCHAR2(14) 
DESTINATARIO_NOME              VARCHAR2(50) 
DESTINATARIO_CNPJ              VARCHAR2(14) 
SERIE_NOTA                     VARCHAR2(3)  
TERCEIRO_NOME                  VARCHAR2(50) 
MOTORISTA                      VARCHAR2(80) 
ROMANEIO                       VARCHAR2(10) 
VALOR_MERCADORIA               NUMBER(14,2) 
VALOR_FRETE                    NUMBER(14,2) 
ENDERECO_DESTINATARIO          VARCHAR2(50) 
REGIAO                         VARCHAR2(50)
```

Comment: VW_INFOGED é tabela ou view ?

Comment: VW_INFOGED é uma view

Comment: A view deve ter alguma conversão de data não tratando o formato da "session" , um TO_DATE sem o parametro de formato (2º parâmetro).

Comment: Não entendi muito , tenho que passar o TO_DATE onde ?

Comment: Publica o 'code' da view

Comment: Cara eu sou muito leigo , quando se trata de Oracle rsrs, desculpe. O voce quis dizer com publicar o codigo da view?

Comment: O "SELECT" da view.

Comment: Esse "SELECT * FROM SGT.VW_INFOGED";? ou quer ver a estrutura da view ?

Comment: O sql da estrutura da view , o problema deve estar lá.

Comment: entendi. ou atualizar minha pergunta

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta

Comment: O sql que gera a view tambémn, create or replace view ....

Comment: Justamente , eu não tenho acesso a esse sql , pois eu apenas faço uma conexao nesse banco para uma integração

Comment: Você tem de ver com a a área que dá suporte a isto , tenho quase certeza que o erro está na view.

Comment: É, consegui resolver, na hora de criar a view o cara tava dando um where com data , ai por isso o erro. Ai para ele colocar  um TO_DATE e resolveu. Valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na hora de criar a view o cara tava dando um where com data , ai por isso o erro. Ai falei para ele colocar um TO_DATE e resolveu.